# Installing .Net Core Runtime on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8

I have installed the latest version of the Asp.Net Core runtime onto my Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8.5.9600.16384 (the x64 installer from here);

[Core 2.0.6 Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.6)

If I run the command `dotnet --info` in powershell on the machine I get the output;

> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.6
>
> Build    : 74b1c703813c8910df5b96f304b0f2b78cdf194d

As expected. However, when I publish a .Net Core WebApi which is relying on some of these binaries (not in self hosted mode, if I do this then the site runs ok).

I get a 502.5 error. I have gone into IIS manager and looked at the application pool on the website in question. I only have the options for;

.Net Clr Version v4.0.30319 and .Net Clr Version v2.0.50727

the latter of which was selected and ran fine when I was looking to use Core 2.0.5 binaries.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here to get 2.0.6 to appear?

Comment: Might be worth having [a read of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) - in particular it [specifically says to not use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index/_static/edit-apppool-ws2016.png?view=aspnetcore-2.1) a .net runtime in the IIS config (though it does also say it's optional, so I guess the real answer is "it doesn't matter" - ie there's something else at play).  I haven't done this myself, hence only a comment and not an answer... good luck!

Comment: You could run .Net Core without IIS also.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah I saw that link. I want to use the code runtime files on the server really, as I have a number of code applications running on it. This is mainly for size though as the publish jumps up to around 15 mins. Which isn’t great.

Comment: @PmanAce correct and it works if I do this. But then I have to worry about publish times growing massively.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn hmm, I can't help you with publish times growing, sorry!